# Error in Linked List Implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following is an excerpt from the code to a singly linked list implementation from *Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ (2nd Edition)* by Adam Drozdek that involves deleting a node with a given value.

```
IntNode *tmp = head->next;
head = head->next;
delete tmp;
```

(*head* is defined elsewhere as an IntNode*) Are there typos in this code fragment, or is my mental processor incorrect in that *head* will always be a null pointer after every execution of the above code fragment?

Comment: Nothing is being set to `NULL` in the above code...

Comment: `delete tmp != (tmp = nullptr)`

Comment: I want to make sure I'm interpreting the code right. Consider a linked list with two nodes - 1 (head) and 2. The first line of code has _tmp_ point to _head->next_ which is node 2. The second line has _head_ point to _head->next_ which is also node 2. The third line frees up space pointed to by _tmp_ -- node 2. So wouldn't invoking *head in the future cause the program to crash because the space pointed to by _tmp_ was freed up? And if not crash, it will surely cause bugs will it not?

Comment: @JellalF: That's absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my thought process Oli! I felt like I was missing something since I presumed the code in a textbook would be bug-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `delete tmp`, you are deleting the object pointed to by `tmp`. However, after deleting `head` will still point to the same place. Dereferencing it (`*head`) will cause problems, because the object `head` is pointing to has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant to ask, but I made the assumption that delete would also set the respective pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

No, it'll point to what was the second element of the list (now the first).

Comment: Of course, if the head is the only element in the list then head->next will be NULL initially and head will be NULL afterwards.

Comment: But that element will now be deleted.